# Unable to use wireless network interface (Lubuntu Linux 4.8.0)

Tags: drivers, wireless, lubuntu, broadcom

I'm in charge of maintaining some personal computers. One of them is an old Dell Laptop which previously had Windows XP. The Windows XP WiFi drivers were working but Lubuntu was unable to install the proprietary drivers. Since then the WiFi is not working anymore. After I tried to reinstall bc43 drivers for the BCM4318 I got several errors and are still unable to reach the network. Wired networking is possible and working fine.

Starting with the devices which I expect to be incompatible with the driver

Part of lspci:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
Subsystem: Dell BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 64
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
Region 0: Memory at dfbfc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: b44
Kernel modules: b44

02:03.0 Network controller: Broadcom Limited BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1370 WLAN Mini-PCI Card
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at dfbfe000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
    Kernel modules: ssb, wl
```

The name resolution:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search fritz.box
```

route -n is empty for wlan0

For the wpa_supplicant configuration I have copied the default-configuration and changed network according to the network.

```
network={
    ssid="TheSSID"
    psk="ThePSK"
}
```

The device is visible under /sys/class/net/wlan0 but it never sended or received data.

```
wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:16:ce:13:6b:07  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Interfaces:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
metric 10
```

Ping 127.0.0.1 works. Ping anyone - network is unreachable.

```
Module                  Size  Used by
b43                   397312  0
bcma                   53248  1 b43
mac80211              679936  1 b43
mii                    16384  1 b44
ssb                    57344  2 b43,b44
b44                    36864  0
cfg80211              512000  3 wl,b43,mac80211
wl                   6152192  0
```

And since I tryed to install b43 fwcutter firmware b43 installer which once stuck heavy while installing I now have a kernel-stacktrace:

```
[    7.871943] ---[ end trace 5fef9210590c92d1 ]---
[   13.418691] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   14.703204] random: crng init done
[   15.124649] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   15.318497] systemd[1]: systemd 231 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
[   15.318716] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86.
[   15.335972] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <AM01>.
[   17.151920] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[   17.152188] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[   17.152281] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[   17.152324] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[   17.152633] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[   17.193800] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[   17.206690] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[   18.121157] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   18.193634] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   21.957169] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   22.244826] systemd-journald[280]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   23.990828] intel_rng: FWH not detected
[   24.286733] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[   25.416479] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
[   26.698841] gpio_ich: ACPI BAR is busy, GPI 0 - 15 unavailable
[   26.699334] gpio_ich: GPIO from 446 to 495 on gpio_ich
[   27.446029] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for STAC9200: line_outs=1 (0xe/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   27.446035] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   27.446039] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0xd/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   27.446041] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   27.446043] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
[   27.446046] snd_hda_codec_idt hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x10
[   27.665018] input: HDA Intel Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
[   27.665168] input: HDA Intel Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
[   29.751314] wl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   29.751323] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   29.751325] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   29.770517] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   31.424692] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4318 WLAN found (core revision 9)
[   31.468084] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 3, Type 2 (G), Revision 7
[   31.468107] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2050, Revision 8, Version 0
[   31.484315] Broadcom 43xx driver loaded [ Features: PNL ]
[   32.333064] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[   33.295198] audit: type=1400 audit(1479222648.700:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=587 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.295216] audit: type=1400 audit(1479222648.700:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium" pid=587 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.706084] audit: type=1400 audit(1479222649.112:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=611 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.706102] audit: type=1400 audit(1479222649.112:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=611 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.706112] audit: type=1400 audit(1479222649.112:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=611 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   33.706121] audit: type=1400 audit(1479222649.112:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=611 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.705842] audit: type=1400 audit(1479222650.112:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince" pid=615 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.705862] audit: type=1400 audit(1479222650.112:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper" pid=615 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.705872] audit: type=1400 audit(1479222650.112:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer" pid=615 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   34.705882] audit: type=1400 audit(1479222650.112:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper" pid=615 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   36.468150] Adding 1037820k swap on /dev/mapper/cryptswap1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1037820k FS
[   37.672053] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[   37.812176] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   47.746120] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   47.753552] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   47.910162] NET: Registered protocol family 4
[   47.927624] NET: Registered protocol family 5
[   50.848196] b44 ssb1:0 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
[   50.848200] b44 ssb1:0 eth0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[   50.848297] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 4463.740167] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[ 4463.841285] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
[ 4467.840076] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[ 4467.989240] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5591
[ 4467.989245] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4467.989248] usb 1-1: Product: Ultra USB 3.0
[ 4467.989251] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 4467.989253] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 4C530001080909115001
[ 4468.211301] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4468.220102] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 4468.220203] scsi host2: runtime PM trying to activate child device host2 but parent (1-1:1.0) is not active
[ 4468.220332] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 4468.257284] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[ 4469.251186] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra USB 3.0    1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 4469.257948] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 4469.258403] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 60062500 512-byte logical blocks: (30.8 GB/28.6 GiB)
[ 4469.259780] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 4469.259786] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 4469.261788] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 4469.281323]  sdb: sdb1
[ 4469.284789] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 4579.371926] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[ 4802.456036] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 4802.605151] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5591
[ 4802.605155] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4802.605158] usb 1-1: Product: Ultra USB 3.0
[ 4802.605161] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 4802.605163] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 4C531001490811105330
[ 4802.610058] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4802.612673] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 4802.612749] scsi host2: runtime PM trying to activate child device host2 but parent (1-1:1.0) is not active
[ 4803.617474] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra USB 3.0    1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 4803.621051] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 4803.621561] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 60062500 512-byte logical blocks: (30.8 GB/28.6 GiB)
[ 4803.623302] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 4803.623308] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 4803.625583] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 4803.637723]  sdb: sdb1
[ 4803.641569] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 4807.712838] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 4807.776291] FAT-fs (sdb1): unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty
[ 4815.768049] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4815.917162] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5591
[ 4815.917167] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4815.917169] usb 1-1: Product: Ultra USB 3.0
[ 4815.917172] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 4815.917174] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 4C531001490811105330
[ 4815.922030] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4815.923790] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 4815.923854] scsi host2: runtime PM trying to activate child device host2 but parent (1-1:1.0) is not active
[ 4816.929472] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Ultra USB 3.0    1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 4816.931962] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 4816.933574] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 60062500 512-byte logical blocks: (30.8 GB/28.6 GiB)
[ 4816.934948] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 4816.934953] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 4816.935956] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 4816.949112]  sdb: sdb1
[ 4816.952846] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 4817.285863] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[ 4884.763293] usercopy: kernel memory exposure attempt detected from c0098000 (dma-kmalloc-512) (4096 bytes)
[ 4884.763333] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 4884.763408] kernel BUG at /build/linux-yFroJZ/linux-4.8.0/mm/usercopy.c:75!
[ 4884.763484] invalid opcode: 0000 [#1] SMP
[ 4884.763529] Modules linked in: nls_iso8859_1 uas usb_storage nls_utf8 isofs appletalk ipx p8023 p8022 psnap llc arc4 b43 dm_crypt bcma mac80211 wl(POE) snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core gpio_ich dell_laptop snd_hwdep dell_smbios snd_pcm snd_timer snd cfg80211 soundcore dcdbas input_leds joydev serio_raw shpchp lpc_ich mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper b44 syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops psmouse ssb drm mii pata_acpi video
[ 4884.764007] CPU: 0 PID: 2636 Comm: lshw Tainted: P        W  OE   4.8.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu
[ 4884.764007] Hardware name: Dell Inc. ME051                           /0GD366, BIOS A10 11/07/2006
[ 4884.764007] task: f5d88940 task.stack: e6f1e000
[ 4884.764007] EIP: 0060:[<d41f6d93>] EFLAGS: 00010282 CPU: 0
[ 4884.764007] EIP is at __check_object_size+0x123/0x12c
[ 4884.764007] EAX: 0000005e EBX: c0098000 ECX: f71b5144 EDX: f71b0884
[ 4884.764007] ESI: 00001000 EDI: d4a5677b EBP: e6f1fee0 ESP: e6f1feb8
[ 4884.764007]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
[ 4884.764007] CR0: 80050033 CR2: bfcde000 CR3: 26e4b9e0 CR4: 000006f0
[ 4884.764007] Stack:
[ 4884.764007]  d4a5cb38 d4a5fade d4a93cc2 c0098000 f6c02080 00001000 c0099000 c0098000
[ 4884.764007]  000a0000 00001000 e6f1ff1c d4504636 00008000 00001000 bfcd68a4 00008000
[ 4884.764007]  00098000 00000000 000a0000 00000000 000a0000 00000000 d4504590 e6f1ff60
[ 4884.764007] Call Trace:
[ 4884.764007]  [<d4504636>] read_mem+0xa6/0x1f0
[ 4884.764007]  [<d4504590>] ? write_mem+0x1f0/0x1f0
[ 4884.764007]  [<d41fa9af>] __vfs_read+0x1f/0x50
[ 4884.764007]  [<d41fb0af>] vfs_read+0x7f/0x140
[ 4884.764007]  [<d480a430>] ? down_write+0x10/0x40
[ 4884.764007]  [<d41fc239>] SyS_read+0x49/0xb0
[ 4884.764007]  [<d40038ad>] do_fast_syscall_32+0x8d/0x140
[ 4884.764007]  [<d480c47a>] sysenter_past_esp+0x47/0x75
[ 4884.764007] Code: 89 74 24 14 0f 44 ca ba de fa a5 d4 89 44 24 10 0f 44 d7 89 5c 24 0c 89 4c 24 08 89 54 24 04 c7 04 24 38 cb a5 d4 e8 25 94 f8 ff <0f> 0b b8 a7 fa a5 d4 eb b9 55 89 e5 57 56 53 83 ec 1c 3e 8d 74
[ 4884.764007] EIP: [<d41f6d93>] __check_object_size+0x123/0x12c SS:ESP 0068:e6f1feb8
[ 4884.780163] ---[ end trace 5fef9210590c92d2 ]---
[ 4888.301742] usercopy: kernel memory exposure attempt detected from c0098000 (dma-kmalloc-512) (4096 bytes)
[ 4888.301783] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[ 4888.301857] kernel BUG at /build/linux-yFroJZ/linux-4.8.0/mm/usercopy.c:75!
[ 4888.301934] invalid opcode: 0000 [#2] SMP
[ 4888.301979] Modules linked in: nls_iso8859_1 uas usb_storage nls_utf8 isofs appletalk ipx p8023 p8022 psnap llc arc4 b43 dm_crypt bcma mac80211 wl(POE) snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_idt snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core gpio_ich dell_laptop snd_hwdep dell_smbios snd_pcm snd_timer snd cfg80211 soundcore dcdbas input_leds joydev serio_raw shpchp lpc_ich mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper b44 syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops psmouse ssb drm mii pata_acpi video
[ 4888.302786] CPU: 0 PID: 2644 Comm: lshw Tainted: P      D W  OE   4.8.0-26-generic #28-Ubuntu
[ 4888.302877] Hardware name: Dell Inc. ME051                           /0GD366, BIOS A10 11/07/2006
[ 4888.302971] task: e6dcae40 task.stack: e6fa6000
[ 4888.303022] EIP: 0060:[<d41f6d93>] EFLAGS: 00010282 CPU: 0
[ 4888.303090] EIP is at __check_object_size+0x123/0x12c
[ 4888.303146] EAX: 0000005e EBX: c0098000 ECX: f71b5144 EDX: f71b0884
[ 4888.303214] ESI: 00001000 EDI: d4a5677b EBP: e6fa7ee0 ESP: e6fa7eb8
[ 4888.303281]  DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068
[ 4888.303340] CR0: 80050033 CR2: bf9bc000 CR3: 26e4b520 CR4: 000006f0
[ 4888.303408] Stack:
[ 4888.303434]  d4a5cb38 d4a5fade d4a93cc2 c0098000 f6c02080 00001000 c0099000 c0098000
[ 4888.304013]  000a0000 00001000 e6fa7f1c d4504636 00008000 00001000 bf9b48a4 00008000
[ 4888.304013]  00098000 00000000 000a0000 00000000 000a0000 00000000 d4504590 e6fa7f60
[ 4888.304013] Call Trace:
[ 4888.304013]  [<d4504636>] read_mem+0xa6/0x1f0
[ 4888.304013]  [<d4504590>] ? write_mem+0x1f0/0x1f0
[ 4888.304013]  [<d41fa9af>] __vfs_read+0x1f/0x50
[ 4888.304013]  [<d41fb0af>] vfs_read+0x7f/0x140
[ 4888.304013]  [<d480a430>] ? down_write+0x10/0x40
[ 4888.304013]  [<d41fc239>] SyS_read+0x49/0xb0
[ 4888.304013]  [<d40038ad>] do_fast_syscall_32+0x8d/0x140
[ 4888.304013]  [<d480c47a>] sysenter_past_esp+0x47/0x75
[ 4888.304013] Code: 89 74 24 14 0f 44 ca ba de fa a5 d4 89 44 24 10 0f 44 d7 89 5c 24 0c 89 4c 24 08 89 54 24 04 c7 04 24 38 cb a5 d4 e8 25 94 f8 ff <0f> 0b b8 a7 fa a5 d4 eb b9 55 89 e5 57 56 53 83 ec 1c 3e 8d 74
[ 4888.304013] EIP: [<d41f6d93>] __check_object_size+0x123/0x12c SS:ESP 0068:e6fa7eb8
[ 4888.354339] ---[ end trace 5fef9210590c92d3 ]---
[ 4985.298019] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[ 4985.386353] st: Version 20160209, fixed bufsize 32768, s/g segs 256
```

How can reconfigure the wireless network and remove the non-working drivers?

Edit: **Please let me know what needs improvement.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two wireless drivers loaded for your device and, as always, one is incorrect. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Also, you have a faulty entry in /etc/network/interfaces. It is not only incorrect as written, but entirely needless. Let's remove it:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Return the file to its default state.

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Reboot and let us hear your report.